# To find the limit of a function of several factors, can you find the limit of each factor and multiply the resulting limits together?

Tags: calculus, limits

So I am attempting to compute this limit:

$\lim \limits_{r \to 0} [r \cos^3(\theta) \cdot \cos(r \sin(\theta))]$

My method of going about this was to use the squeezing theorem and compute the limit of $r \cos^3(\theta)$ as $r$ approaches $0$, which turns out to be $0$, and then compute the limit of $\cos(r \sin(\theta)$ as $r$ approaches $0$, which turns out to be $1$. Then by multiplying these two limits together, $1 \times 0=0$, I am claiming that the limit of the original function $r \cos^3(\theta) \cdot \cos(r \sin(\theta))$ is $0$.

My question is whether or not this is a viable method of solving this limit and whether or not my logic is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct, but you're missing one step of reasoning. You said that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{r \to 0} \cos(r \sin(\theta)) = 1.
\end{equation}
This is true, but you didn't say why. The reason is because $\cos$ is a continuous function, so we can put the limit inside the function, as follows:
\begin{align}
\lim_{r \to 0} \cos(r \sin(\theta)) &=  \cos \left(\lim_{r \to 0} r \sin(\theta) \right) \\
&= \cos(0) \\
&= 1.
\end{align}

---

Another way is to use the squeeze theorem right from the start:
\begin{equation}
\left| r \cos^3(\theta) \cdot \cos(r \sin(\theta)) \right| \leq |r|,
\end{equation}
since $\cos$ is bounded by $1$. So, taking the limit as $r \to 0$, immediately gives the answer.